# up grade to ubuntu 15 without loosing apps installed

Tags: upgrade

i have installed ubuntu 14.5 LTS ,now i would like to upgrade it to 15. LTS .Without losing data and other applications i installed on ubuntu 14.4 LTS .Can it possible ?

Comment: Consider upgrading to 16.04 instead, which is a LTS release.

Comment: To complement edwinksl's comment, Ubuntu 15.10 is **no longer supported**, which means no more upgrades and no help from this forum. 16.04 is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

> 14.5 LTS

That is not an existing version. I assume you mean 14.04 LTS?

> 15. LTS

That is not an existing version. I assume you mean 16.04 LTS?

> Can it possible ?

Yes. But I suggest you make a backup of your data. Success depends largely on your accuracy and handling of the upgrade when the upgrade show errors or possible input you need to provide.